# Multiple replace statements alternatively replace specific characters

Tags: php, mysql

I need to remove some all numbers, some special characters and specific parts of text from my database. I have a script that can remove one character at a time but I would like to remove all characters in one time.

The characters and text I need to remove look like this: Dollar, Sterling, Page, .p, ~, . and then the numbers 1-9

For example: I have an entry right now that looks like this: This is a great book, 595 pages .p 595 and costs only $ 54.95

I need to update it so it looks like this: This is a great book, and costs only.

Below is the code snippet for the replace feature I use. I would like to use this set up as I want it to work with the rest of the script. $table is the name, $field is the column name, $search is the value that needs to be replaced and $replace is the value to replace with (blank in my case)

```
if($typeOK) { 
            // CREATE UNIQUE HANDLE FOR update_sql_array
            $handle = $table.'_'.$field;
            if($queryType=='replace') {
                $sql[$handle]['sql'] = 'UPDATE '.$table.' SET '.$field.' = REPLACE('.$field.',\''.$search.'\',\''.$replace.'\')';
            } elseif($queryType=='') {
                $sql[$handle]['sql'] = 'UPDATE '.$table.' SET '.$field.' = REPLACE('.$field.',\''.$keyword1.'\',\''.$replace1.'\')';
            }
```

I can post the whole script if needed.

I have tried using multiple replace statements but when I do so it only executes the last replace statement ignoring the first one.

Comment: Use regular expressions.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot. I have the knowledge of a 5 year old when it comes to creating regex.

Answer (score 0):

Some databases support a function called TRANSLATE, but unfortunately, MySQL is not one of them.  You can do it with nested replaces:

```
set field = replace(replace(replace( . . . (field, '0', ''), '1', '') . . . , '9', '')
```

Not elegant, but it works.

The "..." are intended to show additional calls to replace, as in the following sequence:

```
set field = replace(field, '0', '')

set field = replace(replace(field, '0', ''), '1', '')

set field = replace(replace(replace(field, '0', ''), '1', ''), '2', '')

. . .
```

Comment: I think it may be easier to have PHP do a regex before insertion